# Upgrading VirtualBox 3.2.10 breaks my guest Ubuntu screen resolution

Tags: virtualbox

I had Ubuntu 10.4 working fine with the previous version of VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host.

Then I upgraded to VirtualBox to 3.2.10, reinstalled the Linux Guest Additions, and now I am limited to 1008 x 584 resolution in full-screen mode!  I have reinstalled Guest Additions and rebooted the guest OS several times.

Comment: Is the mouse captured and released as normal when guest additions are installed? i.e. are guest additions installed for the current kernel? Have you tried seamless mode (host-l)?

Comment: @Jonathon, the mouse capture and release works as if guest additions are installed.  Disk sharing with the host OS also works.  Seamless mode works.  So I guess this proves that guest additions is installed.  Just Full-Screen isn't working!

Answer (score 2):

Virtualbox 3.2.12 has been out for a while, maybe that will fix your issue

Answer (score -2):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1153437  This worked for me.

**EDIT:**

I spoke too soon. After a "sleep" it changed to a low resolution again.  And now that I think about it, I really would prefer that Guest Additions would detect things properly instead of me having to edit the xorg.conf myself, mainly because it can probably make it more ideal than what I copy and paste from a web forum.  Any chance of fixing Guest Additions?  Or should I try upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10?